# Why is python code compiling but not doing anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

My code goes through the compiler but doesn't replace what needs to be replaced in the new file. All files are in the same directory and I've tried running it as ./06_1 but nothing changed. Here is the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def replace_and_chars(fname):

    f = open(fname,"r", encoding='windows-1255')
    file_buffer_contents = f.read()
    file_buffer_contents.replace("&","\\x26")
    fout = open(fname.replace(".xml","") + "replaced.xml","w+")
    fout.write(file_buffer_contents)
    fout.close
    f.close()
    
    past = replace_and_chars("06_1.xml")
```

Comment: `file_buffer_contents = file_buffer_contents.replace("&","\\x26")`. `replace` is not in-place.

Comment: The indentation error causes `past = replace_and_chars("06_1.xml")` to be part of the function's definition, making it recursive. Thus you are not calling the function at all after defining it (and if you would, it would create an endless loop).